# maven-exec-plugin not finding resources

Tags: java, maven

I am using the maven exec plugin to run a simple java class. This java class loads a text file. Following the maven way, I have my text file inside:

```
src/main/resources
```

upon compilation, the resources ends up in:

```
target/classes
```

with the compiled sources. When I try to run:

```
maven exec:java
```

I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: text.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

This error goes away if I place text.txt in the ${basedir}, however this is not right because it is not following maven standards. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Can you show us your pom?  Also, the line of code that's throwing this error with some surrounding context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change code to [read it from classpath as a `Resource` instead of reading it as `File`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java/1464366#1464366), maven executes java from your `${basedir}` (where your pom resides)

and your code seems to attempt to look in current directory which is why it fails

Comment: Your link helped me solve my problem, thanks a lot, this explains how some times I was getting this error and sometimes everything worked fine.